# How to configure a custom RestTemplate when using spring-cloud-config-client?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to use spring-cloud-config-client to read my configuration properties from a spring-cloud-config-server application on startup.
My application is a Spring-Boot application and what I need to do is adding a specific header to the request before it is sent to the config server.

I have read the documentation (http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html) and I can't find any way to customize the ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator with a provided RestTemplate.

What would be the best way to do that?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.setRestTemplate()`.  In you configuration class add a `@PostConstruct` method where you could set your `RestTemplate` there.

Comment: Tried that using the following gist, but it appears the @PostConstruct gets run after the properties have already been loaded. Does there need to be some sort of order? 
https://gist.github.com/dwelch2344/3424b7752fbb0172ad89

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer is marked as complete as the solution does not work. If a solution was reached it would be nice to update the answer with an actual solution.

Comment: Yes, the same is true for me. That does not work.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on @spencergibb answer.

- Create a configuration class.

  ```
  @Configuration
  @ConditionalOnClass({ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.class, RestTemplate.class})
  public class ConfigClientBootstrapConfiguration {

      private final ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator locator;

      @Autowired
      public ConfigClientBootstrapConfiguration(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator locator) {
          this.locator = locator;
      }

      @PostConstruct
      public void init() {
          RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
          locator.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
      }

  }
  ```
- Create a `bootstrap.factories` in subdirectory `resources/META-INF`

  ```
  # Bootstrap components
  org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=\
  path.to.config.ConfigClientBootstrapConfiguration
  ```